# Scala Multiply list element to next to each other

Tags: scala

I have a list as below :

`val a = List(1,2,3,4,5,6)`

Now I want to multiply list element to each other as below :

`((1*2),(1*3),(1*4),(1*5),(1*6),(2*3),(2*4),(2*5),(2*6),(3*4),(3*5),(3*6),(4*5),(4*6),(5*6))`

I tried as below :

`a.map(x=>a.tail.filterNot(_.equals(x)).map(y=>(x,y))).flatten`

but it not return as expected tuples.s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a.combinations(2).map(_.product)
```

This produces an `Iterator[Int]`. You can tag a `.toList` on the end if you need a `List` result. This is also safe for any size of `a`, including an empty `List[Int]`.

Comment: From the code in the question I think the expected result is a list of tuples, not a list of the actual multiplication (though the actual title makes it quite unclear). Still the use of `.combinations()` is better than my answer (it does drop duplicates though, which may or may not be the desired behaviour).

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the `.tails` method, which returns:

```
scala> a.tails.toList
res2: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), List(2, 3, 4, 5, 6), List(3, 4, 5, 6), List(4, 5, 6), List(5, 6), List(6), List())
```

Then for every sublist with a size greater than 1, map over the tail, returning tuples. Finally, flatten the resulting list:

```
scala> a.tails.toList.collect { case h::tl if tl != Nil => tl.map(h -> _) }.flatten
res5: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5), (1,6), (2,3), (2,4), (2,5), (2,6), (3,4), (3,5), (3,6), (4,5), (4,6), (5,6))
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know about `tails` :)